# Facebook - graph api 2.x - post missing user_likes field

Tags: facebook

With the 2.x graph api version, access will be removed to fql.
We were using fql to retrieve, from the likes table, if a user have liked a specific post.
How to perform this check now ?
Is it a chance that the post object would be quickly updated with a "user_likes" field as into the comment objetc as?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it looks like the only solution is to go over all the likes and look if the page/user has liked the post manually. :-/

Hope FB will have something for this in next versions of the graph api